# Converge multiple list into a single json string

Tags: c#, json

I need to send data from my game server to the client through json and getting a large sum of data from the database and sending it creates an issue

Currently I am creating multiple list in the call to the database to get the data and now I am stuck because I have the data but in multiple list and I can't figure out how to return the data.

I feel like I should be converting it to JSON here and then returning the json string but its all just really confusing

```
public static void GetLobbyList() {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM que";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, MySQL.mySQLSettings.connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        List<string> uids = new List<string>();
        List<int> bets = new List<int>();
        List<string> games = new List<string>();

        while (reader.Read()) {
            ids.Add((int)reader["id"]);
            uids.Add((string)reader["uid"]);
            bets.Add((int)reader["bet"]);
            games.Add((string)reader["game"]);
        }

        reader.Close();

    }
```

So here I am reading the info from the database and for lack of experience I am adding each data point to a list(which is really ugly and I know there must be a better way)

So essentially I `Grab the data->Parse to json->Send string to client`

If It is possible assuming the data returned is from a table with

id | uid | bet | game

I would Like to return an array in json that looks like

{
 {
  "id" : 1,
  "uid" : "erjfh4982y9hf",
  "bet" : 3,
  "game" : "Snake"
 }
 {
  "id" : 2,
  "uid" : "gsegt34t",
  "bet" : 2,
  "game" : "Snake"
 }
}

Im not too familiar with json and how it works but I do know that it is the only way to send large packets of data from my server to my client because everything has to be converted to bytes before it can be sent and my framework does not support converting list to bytes

Comment: Are you open to creating an object with each list as a property and then serializing that to JSON? You could achieve that with Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @Fabulous You lost me at "each list as a property"

Comment: Hold on, I'm working on an answer.

Comment: You do not "parse to json".  JSON is the serialized form of objects; there are tens of thousands of posts here on serializing to JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you are aiming for, you should create a class to hold the data you have retrieved from the database. In my case I called it `GameObject` and it's defined as follows.

```
public class GameObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public int Bet { get; set; }
    public string Game { get; set; }
}
```

After retrieving the information from the database, you'll need to run code similar to the following.

```
var items = new List<GameObject>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    items.Add(new GameObject
    {
        Id = (int)reader["id"],
        Uid = (string)reader["uid"],
        Bet = (int)reader["bet"],
        Game = (string)reader["game"]
    });
}

// Return the jsonPacket which will contain all the items in json format.
var jsonPacket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

In order for this to work, you'll need to reference the Newtonsoft.Json library from nuget. Open your package manager console and type the following command: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` and it will set it up for you. At the top of our code you'll need to have `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to be able to use the classes inside the library to serialise to Json. On the receiving end you can pass the string to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` and you'll get back your list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list of `object`s and anonymous types. There's also a JSON serializer, `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` included if you add the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly to your references.

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

while (reader.Read()) {
    list.Add(new { id =  (int)reader["id"],
                   uid = (string)reader["uid"],
                   bet = (int)reader["bet"],
                   game = (string)reader["game"], });

}

string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
```